# internal error(00801) on combining two collections in oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

```
hos := hos1 multiset union hos2;
```

The statement throws internal error, where hos, hos1 and hos2 are of same object type

Comment: Can you maybe post a testable version of the code that is causing the problem?

Comment: Add full stack error . Error: PLS-00801: internal error [?????????]

Comment: Error(20,5): PLS-00801: internal error [*** ASSERT at file pdw4.c, line 2076; Type 0x00390DB4 has no MAP method.;

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to have been fixed on Oracle 11.
For previous versions, you need to add a map member function.

```
alter type my_object_type add map member function dummy return number invalidate;
```