# PLSQL - Check if an object exists in a table of objects - type has no map

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a procedure that has got this variables of type table of objects:

```
lsa_final_filter_ports   t_modifylink_multicolumnlist; 
lsa_initial_filter_ports   t_modifylink_multicolumnlist;
```

Definition of `t_modifylink_multicolumnlist` is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "T_MODIFYLINK_MULTICOLUMNLIST" IS TABLE OF o_modifylink_multicolumnlist;
TYPE o_modifylink_multicolumnlist AS OBJECT(some properties);
```

`lsa_final_filter_ports` variable is populated like this

```
SELECT b.name INTO ls_bandwidth_name FROM bandwidth b 
          WHERE b.bandwidthid = lna_compatible_port_bw(i);
          SELECT CAST(MULTISET(SELECT * 
                         FROM TABLE(piosa_all_ports) 
                         WHERE ITEMNAME4 = ls_bandwidth_name) 
              AS t_modifylink_multicolumnlist)
              INTO lsa_final_filter_ports 
              FROM dual;
```

Where `piosa_all_ports` is I/O parameter having same type `t_modifylink_multicolumnlist`
Second parameter is initialized at the beginig of procedure with a second I/O parameter that the procedure has

```
lsa_initial_filter_ports := piosa_filtered_ports;
```

What I want to achieve is to check if an object from `lsa_final_filter_ports` exists in `lsa_initial_filter_ports` and if so then skip adding that object in `lsa_initial_filter_ports` which will be an output parameter used by the outside calling procedure.

What I've tried is iterating through `lsa_final_filter_ports` objects and checking if that object already exists like this:

```
FOR i in 1..lsa_final_filter_ports.COUNT LOOP
    IF lsa_final_filter_ports(i) MEMBER OF lsa_initial_filter_ports THEN
        CONTINUE;
    END IF;
    lsa_initial_filter_ports.EXTEND();
    lsa_initial_filter_ports(lsa_initial_filter_ports.COUNT) := lsa_final_filter_ports(i); 
END LOOP;
```

But with this code I'm getting the following error:

> Error: PLS-00801: internal error [*** ASSERT at file pdw4.c, line
>   2181; Type 0x0x7f991127aef8 has no MAP method.;
>   NR_WIZARDVALIDATIONS__CUSTOMISATIONS__B__166833[33]

I'm not sure if this kind of comparation can be made, maybe someone can clarify this.

Thank you

Comment: What Oracle version are you using? From this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35934650/internal-error00801-on-combining-two-collections-in-oracle-10g), this error occurs in Oracle 10g.

Comment: I'm using oracle 11.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you have objects in PlSql, which only exist in RAM (that means those, that are NOT stored persistently in a table), assigning them to another variables always causes a (deep) copy of the origin object.
(which is really a problem, if you often assign objects with nested objects to working-variables and back to the collection ...)

Therefore, you´ll never will be able to compare two (copies) of the same object on object-pointer level.

Only thing you can do, is comparing some unique attributes of the objects.
Let´s say, you´ll have an ID in your `piosa_all_ports`, then you might modify your loop above with the comparison in something similar to this:

```
v_exists integer;
FOR i in 1..lsa_final_filter_ports.COUNT LOOP
    select nvl(max(1),0) 
      from table(lsa_initial_filter_ports) x
     where x.id = lsa_final_filter_ports(i).id;
    if (v_exists = 0) then
       lsa_initial_filter_ports.EXTEND();
       lsa_initial_filter_ports(lsa_initial_filter_ports.COUNT) :=   lsa_final_filter_ports(i); 
   end if;
END LOOP;
```

(rem.: i know, that switching PlSql- and SQL-Context in sample above is time-consuming, but otherwise, you have to write a function that tests the existance of an ID by iterating the whole list)

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was looking for, I've tried it and it works perfectly, thanks a lot